# Can I avoid using live Firebase Storage when using emulators?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

as I patiently wait for Firebase storage to be added to the emulators, I was wondering if there is a way I can avoid modifying live storage files and folders when running hosting / functions in the emulator?

For example I use the following code to delete all the files in a folder. Last night someone accidentally deleted all the documents in our emulator as part of a test and it deleted all the LIVE storage folders as we use an import of real documents into our emulator

```
async function deleteStorageFolder(path:string) {
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
  return bucket.deleteFiles({
    prefix: path
  })
```

Is there any way I can tell firebase to avoid using the production storage APIs when emulators are running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following condition in my function to prevent using firebase storage API when running in emulator:

```
if (process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR == "true") {
  console.log(`Running in emulator, won't call firebase storage`)

} else {
  // Code goes here to run storage APIs
}
```